# Cannot restrict Google API key with YouTube API

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, restriction, google-api-key-restrictions

I have a Google Maps API key that works just fine with domain restrictions. The project has the YouTube API enabled.

I tried it for importing YouTube videos into a WordPress plugin but it wouldn't work, so I created a new API key and restricted it just to the YouTube API.

It would not work until I removed the domain restrictions. I tried the same restrictions I have on my Maps API key and everything I could find but I cannot seem to restrict the key for Google maps and still get it to work.

Are there any limitations on restrictions one can use with the YouTube API?
Thanks

Tried restricting the domain to my website with wildcards and without.
API key would only work with no domain restrictions.